# Is there a way how to do a while loop to avoid RequestLimitExceeded?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I don't want to face this error: `RequestLimitExceeded` so I would rather create a `while loop` which would listen to the exception and repeat itself until there is no `RequestLimitExceeded` exception. However, I can't find a way how to do that.

CODE:

```
ParseObject objectUpdate = ParseObject.createWithoutData("HangOut", 
hangOut.getObjectID());
    objectUpdate.put("Name", name.getText().toString());
    objectUpdate.put("City", autocompleteTV.getText().toString());
    objectUpdate.put("City_Lowercase", 
    autocompleteTV.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
    hangOutUpdate.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
    //somewhere here I would like to check if e is RequestLimitExceeded if             
    //yes, then repeat saveInBackground
            if (e==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Object was edited.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
              }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "An error has occured: "+e.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: If you were going to have a while-loop 'listening for an exception', wouldn't it be just as easy to have a while-loop which kept attempting to perform a save, until a `RequestLimitExceeded` *wasn't* returned?

Comment: But what would I do then? Create while loop and put saveInBackground command inside? Then it would not wait until it's done, it would call the function too frequently which might cause duplicates or unneeded requests to server. I could put some delay but the delay value depends on internet speed etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like this?

```
private void save() {
    hangOutUpdate.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Object was edited.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else if (e instanceof RequestLimitExceeded) {
                save(); // How many times you do this is your business...
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "An error has occured: "+e.toString(), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is the solution, very nice! :) Thanks. I haven't tried it yet. As soon as I try it I will mark it as correct answer. So far you have my ++.